# php - find a specific character after and before a string

Tags: php

How can I find the first occurrence of double quote `"` after and before a string. Of course, I used `preg_match_all()` to find all the `.jpg` extensions and I want to find the first occurrence of `"` after and before this extension. I went over `strpos()` and `substr()`, but I could not make it. What is the fastest way of doing it?!

For example:

```
<div data-img="/path/to/the/file.jpg"></div>
```

or maybe

```
<img src="/path/to/the/file.jpg"/>
```

I just want to get the first occurence of `"` before and after each `.jpg` that I get from `preg_match_all()` and then get the path between double quotations!

Comment: Can you show an example of desired input/output?

Comment: @NijrajGelani What I meant was not so hard. The example was of course repeating the statement above!!!

Comment: Why don't you just make the regexp match the whole string between the double quotes?

Comment: This is the regexp: `/"[^"]*\.jpg"/`

Comment: @Barmar I am not really familiar with regexp that much

Comment: Then go to www.regular-expression.info and learn.

Comment: Ok, thanks :) I will absolutely do it

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for, the first '"' before '.jpg' and the one after?

```
$path   = array();
$subst  = strpos( $s, '.jpg' );
while ( $subst !== false ) {
    $before = strrpos( $s, '"', -$subst ) + 1;
    $after  = strpos( $s, '"', $subst );
    $path[] = substr( $s, $before, $after - $before );
    $subst  = strpos( $s, '.jpg', $after + 1 );
}
```

**Edit:** Fixed the code and now it will actually find the position of the '"' before and after the substing '.jpg', if this is what you were looking for.

**Edit2:** Added how to get the filename between the quotes.

**Edit3:** After seeing your answer, I finally understood the question! This is how it is done with string comparisons!

Answer (score 1):

Great thanks to **Barmar** . This will help those who may have the same question:

```
preg_match_all('/"[^"]*\.jpg"/', $string, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```